# C# Windows Universal App MediaElement playing AAC-LC/m4a audio data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement, aac, m4a

I am using MediaCapture class to record voice in aac-lc/m4a format. I am trying to play same audio data on MediaElement. It is not playing the m4a audio. However if i record the voice in 'WAV' format, MediaElement is able to play the audio without any issues. I tried with all possible MIME Types for aac-lc/m4a audio.

Here is the player code:
    
    `var inMemoryRas = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var writeStream = inMemoryRas.AsStreamForWrite();
    await writeStream.WriteAsync(audioData, 0, audioData.Length);
    await writeStream.FlushAsync();
    inMemoryRas.Seek(0);
    mMediaPlayer_.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.ForegroundOnlyMedia;
    String mimeType_ = "";
    mMediaPlayer_.SetSource(inMemoryRas, mimeType_);
    mMediaPlayer_.AutoPlay = true;
    mMediaPlayer_.Play();`

I tried with following set of mime types, still no help.

> audio/mpeg, audio/mp4, audio/aac, video/mp4, audio/m4a

Again if i record the audio in wav format it plays without any issues.

Here is the recorder code:

```
 
    MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = null;
    recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.AudioEncodingQuality.Low);
    mRecordingStream_ = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StartRecordToStreamAsync(recordProfile, mRecordingStream_);
```

I appreciate any help on this, Thanks in advance.